# Type mismatch when setting table value

Tags: nim-lang

Hi im trying to do a basic example with tables:

```
import std/tables
let tableTest = initTable[int, string]()
tableTest[2] = "hello world"
```

Here is the playground link:
https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=4FuH

However I'm getting an error when I run the code:

```
Hint: used config file '/playground/nim/config/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: used config file '/playground/nim/config/config.nims' [Conf]
.................................................................................
/usercode/in.nim(3, 10) Error: type mismatch
Expression: `[]=`(tableTest, 2, "hello world")
  [1] tableTest: Table[system.int, system.string]
  [2] 2: int literal(2)
  [3] "hello world": string

Expected one of (first mismatch at [position]):
[0] proc `[]=`(s: var string; i: BackwardsIndex; x: char)
[0] proc `[]=`[A, B](t: OrderedTableRef[A, B]; key: A; val: sink B)
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the mutability of `tableTest`. In this case, the variable `tableTest` is declared immutable with the keyword `let`. To mutate, or assign a key and value pair, declare it like: `var tableTest = initTable[int, string]()`.

Looks like the position hint in the error message is not accurate for subscripts. It should have the index `[1]` as position to show you that all these have in common is that they are either `ref` or `var` which are both mutable.

Read more on [var](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-var-statement) and [let](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-let-statement).

Comment: Thanks setting it to var worked. I thought even if the tableTest symbol was immutable, the table contents itself would be able be changed. On closer inspection the table docs though, it says "For consistency with every other data type in Nim these have value semantics, this means that = performs a copy of the hash table." So to nim a Table is pretty much a value type?

Comment: A *normal* table does, you are correct on that. For ref-semantics there's still `TableRef` - which is identical in behaviour to table except that it has ref sematnics. All you need for that would be to change the function from `initTable` (init tends to be only for value types) to `newTable` (new tends to be only for ref types) ;-)
Note that it is actually true in general that on a ref-type let only guarantees you that the pointer doesn't change, on ref-types you will always be able to change the data.